# html, js and php, sending radio button in form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, radio-button

I'm having problems adding radio buttons to this form. I don't get the code to send the radio button data to email. I'm using these files: https://github.com/myprogrammingblog/myprogrammingblog.com/tree/master/UI%20Components/contact%20form and then added following to html file:

```
  <input type="radio" name="pipelineType" value="3d" checked id="3d" onclick="displayType('3d')">Yes </td>
           <input type="radio" name="pipelineType" value="3d" id="3d" onclick="displayType('3d')"> No </td>
```

I tried tweaking the js and php files but it made the form totally unfunctional. Any ideas?

-Thank you

edit: gives this when trying to run it: GET http://www.yourdomain.com/js/contact_me.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 274ms]
21:00:23.196 SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal contact_me.js:20
21:00:23.204 Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Comment: Are you getting any JS error in browser's console?

Comment: what displayType function is doing?

Comment: active or unactivate radio button when other is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to correct your html input fields, end them proper like below code :

```
   <td> 
      <input type="radio" name="pipelineType" value="3d" checked id="3d" onclick="displayType('3d')" />Yes 
    </td>
```

you have single radio button field with same value so remove one.

Comment: Thank you did that. I just don't know what I should do to js and php files.

Comment: @user3333909 please accept the answer and vote up if it resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

In HTML (file form.html)

```
<form name="sentMessage" class="well" id="contactForm"  novalidate>
    <input type="radio" name="pipelineType" value="3d" checked id="3d" onclick="displayType('3d')">Yes </td>
    <input type="radio" name="pipelineType" value="no_3d" id="no_3d" onclick="displayType('no_3d')"> No </td>

    ...
</form>
```

in contact form/js/contact_me.js

```
$(function() {

        $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation(
            {
                submitSuccess: function ($form, event) {
                    //..your code
                    //todo: adding pipelineType to data and submit to server
                    let pipelineType = document.querySelector('[name="pipelineType"]:checked').value
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "./bin/contact_me.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {name: name, email: email, message: message, pipelineType: pipelineType},

                        ///....
                    });
                }
            })
    });
```

in contact form/bin/contact_me.php

```
<?php
    //
$name = $_POST['pipelineType'];//value will be 3d or no_3d
    //...
```